# Is there a term for words that modify the intensity of something

Tags: terminology, semantics, adverbs

Is there a term for words such as `very` `extremely` `likely` `super` , which modify the intensity of something?

Obviously these are all adverbs, but `yesterday` is also an adverb, and that does not change the intensity of something

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are called [intensifiers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensifier). This term is pretty widespread, and I couldn't think of another.